# Join Broken SQL statements

Tags: sql, perl, parsing, sed, awk

I have a file in Unix which has millions of SQL statements.
Now some of them are broken into multiple lines. Obviously I want them to combine to a single line using sed or awk or whatever for processing.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO EMP
(EMP,ENAME)
VALUES
('1', 'John');
```

or

```
UPDATE EMP SET
ENAME='Samantha' WHERE
DEPT=20;
```

Now the file can also contain SQL set statements like:

```
set term off;
```

We dont need to do anything with such lines.

So basically we need to find lines starting with 'INSERT' or 'UPDATE' or 'DELETE' and then start searching for next semicolon in multi lines and join such lines to form a single line. Can we achieve it in awk/sed/perl?

Comment: "*Obviously* I want them to combine to a single line". To me, this is not obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method with `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s",$0}/;$/{print ""}' file
```

**Demo:**

```
$ cat file
INSERT INTO EMP
(EMP,ENAME)
VALUES
('1', 'John');
UPDATE EMP SET
ENAME='Samantha' WHERE
DEPT=20;
set 
term 
off;

$ awk '{printf "%s",$0}/;$/{print ""}' file
INSERT INTO EMP(EMP,ENAME)VALUES('1', 'John');
UPDATE EMP SETENAME='Samantha' WHEREDEPT=20;
set term off;
```

Use redirection to store the change to a newfile:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s",$0}/;$/{print ""}' file > newfile
```

Comment: Nice try and I am impressed, but comments will create a problem: `code`$ cat file.sql --COMMENT SET DEFINE OFF; INSERT INTO EMP (EMP,ENAME) VALUES ('1', 'John'); UPDATE EMP SET ENAME='Samantha' WHERE DEPT=20; set term off; $ awk '{printf "%s",$0}/;$/{print ""}' file.sql --COMMENTSET DEFINE OFF; INSERT INTO EMP(EMP,ENAME)VALUES('1', 'John'); UPDATE EMP SETENAME='Samantha' WHEREDEPT=20; set term off;`code`

Answer (score 0):

`awk '/^INSERT|^UPDATE|^DELETE/{i=1} /;/{i=0} {printf("%s ",$0);if(!i) print""}' <filename>`
this will find the Keywords and then set a flag, which will be reset only when a `;` is found. Now till the flag is set, newline won't be printed. So it will take care if the `;` is present in the same line, if any other words are there without `;`, it will not touch those

Experiment

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat log
INSERT INTO EMP;
(EMP,ENAME)
VALUES
('1', 'John');
set term off;
UPDATE EMP SET
ENAME='Samantha' WHERE
DEPT=20;
INSERT INTO EMP
(EMP,ENAME)
VALUES
('1', 'John');
[[bash_prompt$]]$ awk '/^INSERT|^UPDATE|^DELETE/{i=1} /;/{i=0} \
{printf("%s ",$0);if(!i) print""}' log
INSERT INTO EMP;
(EMP,ENAME)
VALUES
('1', 'John');
set term off;
UPDATE EMP SET ENAME='Samantha' WHERE DEPT=20;
INSERT INTO EMP (EMP,ENAME) VALUES ('1', 'John');
```